# Groovy string replaceAll not working properly as expetcted

Tags: regex, groovy

Hy Everyone!

I have a problem with Groovy ReplaceAll in JMeter JSR223. In one case it works, in another case it doesn't.

Have already trye and Sampler, and Preprocessor. But nothing changes.

Jmeter 5.1.1
JSR223 Sampler and JSR223 PreProcessor

1. bodyData Template (JSR223 PreProcessor)
2. Simple Controller
3. HTTP Sampler (HTTP Request)
4. bodyData ReplaceAll (JSR223 PreProcessor)

-------------- WORKING -----------------

```
def bodyData_3DS_default = '' +
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '<soap:Body>' +
        '<ns3:sendSms xmlns:ns2="" xmlns:ns3="">' +
            '<customerId>' + '$' + '{customerId}' + '</customerId>' +
            '<customerType>' + '$' + '{customerType}' + '</customerType>' +
            '<phone>' + '$' + '{phone}' + '</phone>' +
            '<templateId>' + '$' + '{templateId}' + '</templateId>' +

            '<!--Optional:-->' +
            '<smsFlag>' + '$' + '{smsFlag}' + '</smsFlag>' +
            '<callingSystemName>' + '$' + '{callingSystemName}' + '</callingSystemName>' +
        '</ns3:sendSms>' +
    '</soap:Body>' +
'</soap:Envelope>';
bodyData_3DS_default = bodyData_3DS_default.replaceAll('<!--[A-Za-z_0-9:<>${}/ ]*-->', '');
vars.put('bodyData_3DS_default', bodyData_3DS_default);
```

### JSR223 PREPROCESSOR

```
def bodyData = '${bodyData_3DS_default}';
['smsFlag'].each { removeOptional ->
    bodyData = bodyData.replaceAll('<'+ "${removeOptional}" + '[A-Za-z_0-9:<>${}()/_]*' + "</${removeOptional}" + '>', '');
}
vars.put('bodyData', bodyData);
```

-------------- RESULT ----------------

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns3:sendSms xmlns:ns2="" xmlns:ns3=""><customerId>CUSTOM</customerId><customerType>PHYSICAL</customerType><phone>79990001122</phone><templateId>000000006</templateId><callingSystemName>acs</callingSystemName></ns3:sendSms></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

------------ NOT WORKING ---------------------------

```
def bodyData_Services_default = '' +
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '<soap:Body>' +
        '<ns3:sendSms xmlns:ns2="" xmlns:ns3="">' +
            '<customerId>' + '$' + '{customerId}' + '</customerId>' +
            '<customerType>' + '$' + '{customerType}' + '</customerType>' +
            '<phoneAlgorithm>' + '$' + '{phoneAlgorithm}' + '</phoneAlgorithm>' +
            '<text>' + '$' + '{textSms}' + '</text>' +
                '<!--Optional:-->' +
            '<smsFlag>' + '$' + '{smsFlag}' + '</smsFlag>' +
            '<callingSystemName>' + '$' + '{callingSystemName}' + '</callingSystemName>' +          
        '</ns3:sendSms>' +
    '</soap:Body>' +
'</soap:Envelope>';
bodyData_Services_default = bodyData_Services_default.replaceAll('<!--[A-Za-z_0-9:<>${}/ ]*-->', '');
vars.put('bodyData_Services_default', bodyData_Services_default);
```

### JSR223 PREPROCESSOR

```
def bodyData = '${bodyData_Services_default}';
['smsFlag'].each { removeOptional ->
    bodyData = bodyData.replaceAll('<'+ "${removeOptional}" + '[A-Za-z_0-9:<>${}()/_ ]*' + "</${removeOptional}" + '>', '');
}
vars.put('bodyData', bodyData);
```

--------- RESULT ------------------------------

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns3:sendSms xmlns:ns2="" xmlns:ns3=""><customerId>CUSTOM</customerId><customerType>PHYSICAL</customerType><phoneAlgorithm>last_updated_first</phoneAlgorithm><text>teXT</text><smsFlag>true</smsFlag><callingSystemName>blankpin</callingSystemName></ns3:sendSms></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?  Regular expressions and XML are a route fraught with problems, there might be another way if you can explain what you're expecting to happen, and how it isn't happening in the second example?

Comment: I have tryed to use one universal XML and after it remove optional parameters as for uniq case.

I do not understand why in first case it works and in second case not.